# AVPlayer layer is not fitting to the player view

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, ios-autolayout, avplayerlayer

I have implemented AV Video player view and the player layer is not fitting for the bigger screen iPhones such as 6 - 8 plus and iPhone XS Max.

My Player view is in gold color it means the player view's constraints are adapting screen edges so the problem is in AVPlayerLayer.

Please check my codes below and suggest me with working code snippets according to my code base.

```
func setupVideoBg(){
        // Load the video from the app bundle.
        let videoURL: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")! as NSURL

        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
        player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        player?.isMuted = true

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

       // playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
        playerLayer.zPosition = -1
    //    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.videoView.frame.size.width, height: self.videoView.frame.size.height)
        playerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds
       // playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds


        videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        player?.play()

        //loop video
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector
                                                (self.loopVideo),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func loopVideo() {
        player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        player?.play()
    }
```

[image: videoview in iphonexs max]

Comment: show your code on how you set the `AVPlayerLayer`

Comment: sorry I forgot add

Comment: @Sh_Khan code added, please check

Comment: where you call `setupVideoBg` ??

Comment: In viewDidload()

Comment: sorry it's not inside viewDidload actually it's a custom cell and i called in -  override func awakeFromNib() {} method

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
private func tutorialPlayerSetup(with videoName: String) {
    guard let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoName, withExtension:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("video.mp4 not found")
        return
    }
    let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
    
    // configure player
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.tutorialVideoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.masksToBounds = true
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resize
    
    // add player layer to view layer
    playerLayer.frame = self.tutorialVideoView.bounds
    player.play()
}
```

Try this code snippet, the reason is you are setting your frame before adding the layer to the bound of preview View.

```
  playerLayer.frame = self.tutorialVideoView.bounds
```

The above code snippet is very crucial and you should think about the flow how the video layer is going to be loaded. If it is added before the frame is decided it will not fit as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Here are your possible issues without seeing how you set up your videoView.layer:

1  playerLayer.zPosition = -1

(you may have a reason to change your zPos, however you can simply change the layer order of your sublayers)

2  playerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds

( if your view layer is wrong, then you are buggered. You can use the width of your videoView.bounds.size.width and set your playerLayer.frame.size.width